# Break line by letters in Android EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How to break Line by letters in android `EditText`, so it became like this:

```
Hello how to br
eak by letters
instead of word
s
```

Instead of this:

```
Hello how to
break by 
letters
instead of 
words
```

The analog in css is `word-break: break-all`

P.S. Of course Text is dynamically changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
// tmpString - the string to display

//15 - no. of letters you want change according to your requirement

```
int index = 0;
StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer(); 
while (index < tmpString.length()) {
    finalString.append(tmpString.substring(index, Math.min(index + 15,tmpString.length()))+"\n");
    index += 15;
}
editText.setText(finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

It calls 'justify text' or 'text justification', but in `Android` it is not supported, at least until now.

There a kind of solution if you want to implement. It is to use `WebView` and load the text in `HTML` format and set the `body` style to `justify`. It is just a solution if you really need 'text justification'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto resize edit text with following properties:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Full EditText layout example:

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:inputType="textMultiLine"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Enter Text"
   android:textColorHint="@color/primary_color"
   android:ems="10"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:id="@+id/message_input"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```